# Outlining Kansas, adding in county boundaries and shapefile of oil and gas fields

Tags: arcgis-pro

I'm extremely new to ArcGIS Pro and still trying to understand the basics.

I need to map out all county boundaries in Kansas but I can't even figure out how to create a state boundary. After I create a state boundary and county boundaries, I need to add in a shapefile that I have on my computer that shows Oil and Gas fields around Kansas. After the fields are placed then I need to add in actual oil and gas wells using their coordinates (I assume that will be through the XY location). I am only focusing on the state of Kansas.

I've been trying to figure out how to do this on my own but have completely stuck.

Comment: Do you actually need to create the Kansas state and country boundaries, or do you just need them as a background?  ArcGIS Pro can display basemaps as backgrounds that will show more detail as you zoom in.  Depending on the basemap you select you might get info such as state and country boundaries

Comment: I need to create them I am pretty sure. It will be underneath the other information (oil and gas fields and then oil and gas wells on top) but I need the boundaries to be clearly visible from any distance.

Answer (score 5):

This data is available online from

```
https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.2017.html
```

cb_2017_us_county_500k.zip   [11 MB]

Unzip and extract the file to a folder

Using ArcGIS Pro - load the data in (add data) in map mode.

using the select by attributes using the expression
STATE='20'
(Kansas is 20 in the dataset)

Then Export the data to a new file.
For a State Boundary you can use the dissolve tool and create another file.

** you might be using a different projection - you might need to ask another question on that topic

[image]